# valueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (46105,1) into shape (46105)?

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

I am developing a hybrid model consisting of a feedforward neural network and random forest classifier using the sklearn ensemble voting Classifier there is no error at fitting/training phase but i got this error at these lines:

**score   = voting_classifier.score(test_x,test_y)

y_pred = voting_classifier_hard.predict(test_x)**

```py
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=35,input_dim = train_x.shape[1], activation="selu",kernel_initializer = 'lecun_normal'))
    model.add(Dense(units=35,activation="selu",kernel_initializer = 'lecun_normal'))
    model.add(Dense(units=35,activation="selu",kernel_initializer = 'lecun_normal'))
    model.add(AlphaDropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
    metrics_list = [
        tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='binary_accuracy'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
        tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
        tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
        tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
        tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
        tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
        
    ]
    model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer,metrics=metrics_list)
    return model

from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

cnn = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)
cnn._estimator_type = "classifier"
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
logits = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0)
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
voting_classifier = VotingClassifier(
    estimators = [('dtc',logits),
                    ('cnn', cnn)],
                voting="hard"
                )

voting_classifier.fit(train_x,train_y)    
score   = voting_classifier.score(test_x,test_y)
y_pred = voting_classifier_hard.predict(test_x)
accuracy = accuracy_score(test_y,y_pred)
print(accuracy)
```

Error message:

`valueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (46105,1) into shape (46105)`

Answer (score 0):

`test_y` needs to be the same shape as the corresponding model prediction. Reshaping `test_y` into (-1, 1) should work.

Comment: i reshape test_y into (-1,43), it gives this error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (46105,1) into shape (46105)

Comment: I don't know why (-1, 43) instead of what I said (-1 ,1). Your model output has the shape of (batch_size, 1) so the true target should have the same shape to make the score calculation work.

Comment: I reshape test_y into (-1,1) it gives this error. ValueError: X has 1 features, but DecisionTreeClassifier is expecting 43 features as input.

Comment: @AsadRaza that's odd. What are the shapes of `train_x` and `train_y`? How is `test_y` the input to your RF classifier?